# Use compass to compile scss file to a different css

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I had a doubt regarding compiling the scss file using compass. For example I have 2 directories, 1 for Sass and another 1 for my CSS files. In my css directory, I have 2 CSS files... "xuvs.css" and "site.css"....

If I make changes in the "xuvs.scss" file, so during the final compilation, by default Compass applies the changes to "xuvs.css"... So is it possible to apply those changes in the "site.css" instead of "xuvs.css" file using compass?

Comment: If you changed xuvs.scss why would site.css change?

Comment: I am a bit new to this and hence wanted to know, if it is possible to do that or not.

Comment: You must have a reason why you believe site.css should change when xuvs.scss is modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Sass and Compass will output `.css` files for any matching `.scss` files that are not prefixed with an underscore. This is why your "css" directory contains the two compiled files: one for each of your `.scss` files.

It is possible to modify `xuvs.scss` and have it compile into `site.css`: you would do this via the [`@import` rule](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import), however, unless you changed the file name of `xuvs.scss` to `_xuvs.scss`, you would still have a separate, compiled file named `xuvs.css`. Files that are prefixed with an underscore are called [partials](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials).

It is considered a ["best practice"](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/best_practices/) to create partials and `@import` them into a single, compiled "base" `.scss` file. In your case, this compiled file would be called `site.css`.